# where to find on backend to amend and edit title tage for each page on website?

Tags: tags

I need to put a title tag on each page of my website but I can only seem to be able to do it for the home page, where can i set and edit the title tags for the other pages?

Answer (score 0):

Titles are handled largely by your theme. In most cases, they combine your site title (as set in your admin under Settings > General > Site Title) and your page/post titles.

If you are not seeing page/post titles appearing in your title tag, then you may want to look into a plugin that allows explicit page-specific control over the title output (again, provided your theme uses the correct output functions).

Check out [All-in-One SEO Pack](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack/) and see if that does what you want.